# Asking Bash to cd into each directory under some path and run a command when it is inside?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, find, cd-command

Take this path for example: `/var/www/html`.

Inside the dir `html`, there are a few subdirectories. I need the system to go into each one of these sub-directories via `cd` (it must be `cd`), and then running a command when it is inside this dir, go back to /var/www/html and so repeat the process with the next dir.

This is what I tried, but it seems ineffective:

```
find /var/www/html/* -type d -maxdepth 0 ! -name 'phpmyadmin' -exec cd * && wp plugin update --all {} \;
```

Comment: Can you add the output of this command?

Comment: This is the output: ```This does not seem to be a WordPress install.```

Comment: It is created from a Bash extension named WP-CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets first take apart your command:

```
find /var/www/html/* -type d -name 'phpmyadmin' -maxdepth 0 ! -exec cd * && wp plugin update --all {} \;
```

What this is actually going to do is:

1. The shell is going to expand `/var/www/html/*`. Lets assume it expands to `/var/www/html/foo` and `/var/www/html/bar`.
2. The shell is going to expand `*` (the one in your `cd *`). Note that this is current working directory. Lets assume you have `pop` and `tart`.
3. The shell is going to run `find /var/www/html/foo /var/www/html/bar -type d -name phpmyadmin -maxdepth 0 ! -exec cd pop tart`.
4. `find` is going to throw an error about an unterminated command, because it saw `-exec` but no `;` or `+`.

So to be clear what's happening, the shell is breaking apart the line, and only passing part of what you meant to be an argument to `find`.

The cleanest, and simplest way to do this with `find` is:

```
find /var/www/html/* -type d -name phpmyadmin -maxdepth 0 -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && wp plugin update --all' -- {} \;
```

This quotes the entire command, feeds it to `sh`, and then passes the directory as an argument.

Also this is personal taste, but for stuff like this, I would say it's easier to not use `find`:

```
for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && wp plugin update --all; done
```

Comment: Hmm, this way with a for loop seems even more piquant. I must say, Bash for loops seem to me a bit different than Javascript for loops...

Answer (score 1):

Let us create a shell script  `tmp.sh` that cd's to your directory and does the work.  Now cd in a child does not influence parent, so after the script exits, you are back in the calling directory

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$1" 
wp plugin update --all
```

and then

```
 type d -name 'phpmyadmin' -maxdepth 0 ! -exec ./tmp.sh '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be with a small for loop.
You could this in one line with

```
for folder in */; do <your-commands-on-$folder>; done
```

Using your example that could be

```
for folder in /var/www/html/*/phpmyadmin/; do cd "$folder"; wp plugin update --all; done
```